# I have this code to fetch the gmail id from device but its not working in 6.0 and above version

Tags: android

I am trying to get primary Hmail id from the device automatically, but its only working in the 5.0 and below version, not working in the 6.0 and above versions.

My code is:

```
private TextView text;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    String email=getEmail(this);
    if(email !=null)
    {
        text.setText(email);
    }
    else {
        text.setText("Account not found");
    }
}

static String getEmail(Context context) {
    AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(context);
    Account account = getAccount(accountManager);

    if(account==null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    else
    {
        return account.name;
    }
}

private static Account getAccount(AccountManager accountManager)
{
    Account[] accounts=accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
    Account account;
    if(accounts.length>0)
    {
        account=accounts[0];
    }
    else {
        account=null;
    }
    return account;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please manage required runtime permission for marshmallow. Like this

First declare two variable in activity

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION = 1;
String mPermission = Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS;
```

After in onCreate method

```
 private void getPermission() {
 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= 23) {

        if (checkSelfPermission(mPermission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{mPermission,
                    },
                    REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION);
            return;
        }

        else
        {
            methodGetGmailAccont();
        }
    }
}

 private void methodGetGmailAccont() {
/* here your logic to get account */ 
}
```

After override onRequestPermissionsResult method like this

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    Log.e("Req Code", "" + requestCode);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION) {
        if (grantResults.length == 1 &&
                grantResults[0] == MockPackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
            /* here permission approve so we called our logic  */

              methodGetGmailAccont()

        }
        else{
            /* here user deny permission,again called method to get permission */
              getPermission();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks u so much, but first time it not showing anything, when i open app 2nd time it showing gmail id.

Comment: bcz you have not maintain permission in proper way, means in onRequestPermissionsResult() method  if condition is true then get gmail account logic apply. if any kind of helpfull when using my code than after please up vote and press right answer. ok i update my ans you can understand easily.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Get accounts permission to manifest. If you have done that then, you need to add run-time permission Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS for Android 6.0 marshmallow to get Google Accounts and gmail id.

First ask the permission to Get accounts and then in onRequestPermissionsResult run your method getEmail to get gmail id.

Happy Coding !!